# How to Secure own iFrame from having the auth Token stolen?

Tags: authentication, security, iframe, web-applications

I am currently facing a problem with creating an iFrame for my ChatBot.

The Situation is as follows. User A wants to embed my ChatBot on his website [www.websiteUserA.com](http://www.websiteUserA.com). User A is recognized by my Backend when he accesses myapp.com and logs in securely using Google Auth.

The problem now is that the customers of User A, that are accessing [www.websiteUserA.com](http://www.websiteUserA.com), need to also be identified as customers of User A. To do that, I thought of introducing a jwt, that I could use the setup claims that I can later check and validate upon making a request.

The problem now, is that if I expose the Token in any kind of form to the frontend. Anyone, a "Hacker", would then be able to identify as "Customer of User A" and could theoretically use the ChatBot on his own Website, while having User A be accounted for all the usage.

This is sadly not possible under any circumstances, to allow such easy impersonation.

To solve this, I thought about introducing allowed domains that User A can set. So [www.websiteUserA.com](http://www.websiteUserA.com) should be the only domain allowed to send me this said jwt Token. Sadly request referrals could be easily spoofed.

Another solution was to maybe only communicate with User A's backend. User A would receive an API Key from me, that is responsible of managing and reissuing these JWT Tokens. This would ensure that the token would never get to the frontend. However the setup could be quite in-intuitive because of the different architectures that could be used to host and manage [www.websiteUserA.com](http://www.websiteUserA.com), let alone the increased load on User A's Backend Server to treat all of these requests.

I have also thought of one last solution. Which is to include the jwt Token in flask sessions (I use flask for my webAPP). The Flask Session is secured with these parameters:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
csrf = CSRFProtect(app)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = SECRET_KEY

app.config['PERMANENT_SESSION_LIFETIME'] = timedelta(minutes=30)
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE'] = True
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY'] = True
app.config['SESSION_COOKIE_SAMESITE'] = 'None'
```

The Goal is to make it somewhat "harder" to extract the jwt Token. It should not be impossible, but these parameters would help protect the token from JavaScript and XSS attacks.

Can you please help me? I Don't know how I should secure my application, as whatever approach I choose, I still find myself vulnerable. Can anyone recommend me a better approach? How do big Tech companies do this? I'd imagine Google, Facebook or any other huge company would easily figure this out.

I just want to provide as safe and as secure of a service as I could :D.

Comment: I thought of another Idea.
I thought maybe I could give User A an API Key, That gets a new token from my server every 5 minutes or so. So the Hacker would constantly be in a race to get the token to only be able to use for a short time.
Not sure if the Hacker could write some Crawler Script that fetches the new Token each time it's made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as 100%. For example, if your user is browsing from a cafe and leaves for the toilet, an attacker may impersonate this user. So there is no such thing as perfect defense and we need to take any solution we may propose with a grain of salt.

First thing's first: **HTTPS**. This way your requests use encryption for the sake of security. Hence, if JWT is a POST parameter or a bearer token under HTTPS, then you will have a fare amount of security.

Next, instead of sending JWT upon every request, you could make it a one-timed token, that is, you would have a blacklist of JWTs that have not expired yet, but were already used. This way, if your user authenticates using a JWT that was valid at the time, then by virtue of using that JWT, the JWT will become invalid and, if an attacker even manages to steal it, it will no longer be useful.

Of course, you will have an actual session id instead of JWT that will serve as the session identifier and JWT will be used for authentication only.

This approach would make it very hard for an attacker to steal JWT and no reward for him/her if he/she even manages to do so, because by the time he/she would use it, the JWT would already be invalid.

A JWT usually contains an expiry date, so when a valid JWT is used up, you can blacklist it and use a cron job that regularly removes expired JWT from blacklisted JWT to avoid piling up too much useful data.

Because, if your JWT has a lifespan of four hours and you use it up now, your JWT being blacklisted, so nobody will reuse it, then after 4 hours it can be removed from the blacklist, because at that point it's simply uninteresting that the JWT was used up, as it's expired anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your suggested approach! I think I'll probably try to implement it. I have 1 other question though. How would I securely provide these JWTs or session IDs to User A's customers without exposing any secrets on the frontend? Maybe backend to backend. Where User A's server asks my server for authentication using the JWT, which my server would return a session ID to, which would then get passed to frontend?

Comment: @ihebsalah you can definitely do it backend to backend, but you should not be afraid of posting JWT. After all, when you log in, you also post sensitive data and you end up with the same dilemma. Luckily, HTTPS (HyperText Transmit Protocol **Secure**) encrypts your post parameters, so posting via HTTPS (and not HTTP) protects the data that you pass. Yes, if someone accesses your browser, then he/she will access sensitive information you send, but as long as you are not afraid posting a username/password, you should not worry about posting JWT perse either.

Comment: @ihebsalah in order to protect JWT, you will just need to make sure that you indeed use https and your app is as secure as possible. Protect it from XSS, SQL injection, template injection and other security issues and you should be fine. Read more here: https://www.linkedin.com/advice/0/what-best-practices-storing-sending-jwt-tokens . If this answer helped you understand how you can solve your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks again bro :D. Is it okay for the JWT of User A to get leaked in this scenario? Because this is a chatbot after all and would be available to the public. The public being the customers of User A.
And if one of these customers were to find the JWT. Then send it to the appropriate api endpoint on my server; They would then get returned a session ID impersonating User A.
Wouldn't this be a bit of a problem?

Comment: The JWT should be related to the end user. So, if you have userA and userA has userA1, userA2, userA3, ... on his turn, then your system should have a JWT to userA1, userA2, ..., that is, a JWT of each user of user A. You would embed userA as well into JWT, so a JWT would definitely belong to a definite customer of yours, but the same JWT would also belong to the user of your customer.

Comment: @ihebsalah for example. Let's suppose that companyX would pick up your chatbot and email a@b.c would be a user of companyX, using your chatbot. Then, companyX would be a paying customer of yours and would request a JWT either via backend-to-backend request, or through the browser. Then the app of companyX would send a request to its own companyX application that would encode the message it would send to your server and then, the browser can send this encoded message to your server and obtain a JWT

Comment: @ihebsalah the JWT having a raw JSON of the like of `{"username": "foobar", "customer": "companyX", "expires": "<some date here>"}`. After encoding, this JWT would uniquely identify a user of companyX and that JWT would be used to authenticate. At the authentication it would be decoded and then it would be blacklisted, so it will never be reused again successfully.

Comment: @ihebsalah, so, let's suppose that userA's app requests a JWT on server-side from your chatbot app for a user and obtains a valid JWT. This JWT on its turn would be given to the browser from userA's app and posted to your IDP (Identity Provider), which on its turn would detect that it's a valid JWT, it has not been used for authentication yet and it has not expired yet either. So it will authenticate you as a user of userA and you will be able to chat normally. Now, let's assume that I somehow obtained your JWT that you used for authentication.

Comment: @ihebsalah your question was how can I be prevented from reusing your JWT and impersonate you. The answer is that if this JWT is blacklisted just after you logged in, then I will be rejected even if I had your JWT. So, if a JWT is considered to be invalid when it was used up for validation, then this kind of data spying will not be very effective.

Comment: @ihebsalah yet, you can decide to perform all this communication from backend to backend, but it comes with some costs for userA. First of all, all the communication to your chatbot will necessarily go through his server. Secondly, he will have to manage the chatbot session server-side and it will be difficult for you to implement a proper SDK for all the different server technologies. Instead, you could implement a Javascript support on your turn and that would work for all browsers and you could also use browser session handling.

Comment: @ihebsalah therefore, a JWT should not be userA-specific, but end-user specific and should offer a one-time authentication support for your scenario, so anyone stealing a JWT would necessarily be a second person using that JWT and at that point the JWT would already be invalid.

Comment: I appreciate your help, thank you so much! So I have decided to issue an API Key to UserA. Then UserA's backend server would make a request to my server, asking me to fetch him a UserA1 specific jwt, that also serves as the session identifier. This session jwt would then be used for the rest of the communications between UserA1 and my chatbot. This way the original UserA would then only have to manage 1 authentication event for each UserA1...UserAn. Only doubt is that I am not sure if this is as significant of an overhead for UserA's backend.

Comment: I still dont understand how I could integrate the one time JWT into this approach. As I wanted to use it now as a short lived session. That I would bind with an ip address as not all UserA1 would be signed up users with emails. They could be public Users with just an ip address.

Comment: but if the approach I mentioned works well. I would be more than happy to implement it

Comment: A one-time JWT approach would work like this: your user's app requests a JWT, so it would receive a JWT that was not used yet for authentication. This JWT would be given to the user who in turn could use it from his browser and after the authentication this JWT would be blacklisted. However, since your user's users are not necessarily authenticated, you cannot really identify them, because they may change IP addresses (think of a user traveling from place to place). Therefore, in your scenario it appears to be the case that you will have a single session for userA

Comment: @ihebsalah and then you could reuse a JWT for the lifetime of the session and operate on server-side, the users of userA would send requests to userA's app which in turn would send requests to your app, but then userA might as well use a normal session ID on their backend, not necessarily JWT.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your help means a lot to me. I wish you a great day bro

Comment: @ihebsalah happy to help. Have a nice day too!